# Monotouch video streaming with MPMoviePlayerController

Tags: xamarin.ios, video-streaming, mpmovieplayercontroller

I am creating a Monotouch iPhone app that will display streaming videos.  I have been able to get the MPMoviePlayerController working with a local file (NSUrl FromFile), but have not been able to get videos streamed from a media server.

Here is the code I am using to play the video:

```
                string url = @"http://testhost.com/test.mp4";
                var nsurl = NSUrl.FromString(url);
                mp = new MPMoviePlayerController(nsurl);
                mp.SourceType = MPMovieSourceType.Streaming;

                //enable AirPlay
                //mp.AllowsAirPlay = true;

                //Add the MPMoviePlayerController View
                this.View.AddSubview(mp.View);

                //set the view to be full screen and show animated
                mp.SetFullscreen(true, true);

                //MPMoviePlayer must be set to PrepareToPlay before playback
                mp.PrepareToPlay();

                //Play Movie
                mp.Play();
```

Is there something else in implementing the MPMoviePlayerController for video streaming that I am missing?  I also read that videos for iOS should be streamed using Apple's HTTP Live Streaming on the media server, is that a requirement?  I have never worked with video streaming on an iOS device before so I am not sure if there is something lacking in my code or the media server setup or a combination.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you need a streaming server to use a video file from an HTTP url. However it's a [requirement](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StreamingMediaGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html) for applications (on the AppStore) to do so:

> Important iPhone and iPad apps that send large amounts of audio or
>   video data over cellular networks are required to use HTTP Live
>   Streaming. See “Requirements for Apps.”

The good news is that your existing code should not have to be changed to handle this (it's server, not client side).

Comment: This would be the more exact, relevant part: `If your app delivers video over cellular networks, and the video exceeds either 10 minutes duration or 5 MB of data in a five minute period, you are required to use HTTP Live Streaming. (Progressive download may be used for smaller clips.)`

Comment: And no, you do not need a streaming server to play video over HTTP. If you do not provide an M3U8, a progressive download will happen.

Comment: After using a sample media file served from Apple, I was able to confirm the code does work.  Thanks.